# Book where a guy goes to different worlds/regions in a boat: in the first, there were ants or tiny humans, and in the second, there were giants

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book when I was a preteen. What I can remember is that a guy traveled to different worlds/places: in the first one, the region was made up of ants or tiny humans, and in the second one, there were giants in the region.

Comment: _[Gulliver's Travels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Travels)_...? If not, in roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: "The Troll" by Ray Bradbury?

Comment: It really does sound like *Gulliver's Travels*, doesn't it?

Comment: Go easy on the OP. Every minute of every day a person is born who has never heard of the works cited in the other responses. Famous works of old can become so buried in newer works that this condition can persist long into adulthood.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1053/

Comment: In Tad Williams' *Otherland* books, the protragonists travel to all sorts of worlds.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland

Comment: Was it by boat or by ship?

Comment: Every now and then I renew a pact with select friends to just stop wasting time with "You've never..?!?" Reach for the pleasure of teaching. The XKCD strip cited by Michael is perfect.

Answer (score 49):

Just knocking out the obvious answer mentioned in the comments, *[Gulliver's Travels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Travels)* by Jonathan Swift matches your description.

> During his first voyage, Gulliver is washed ashore after a shipwreck and finds himself a prisoner of a race of tiny people, less than 6 inches (15 cm) tall, who are inhabitants of the island country of Lilliput. After giving assurances of his good behaviour, he is given a residence in Lilliput and becomes a favourite of the Lilliput Royal Court. He is also given permission by the King of Lilliput to go around the city on the condition that he must not hurt their subjects.

....

> Gulliver soon sets out again. When the sailing ship Adventure is blown off course by storms and forced to sail for land in search of fresh water, Gulliver is abandoned by his companions and left on a peninsula on the western coast of the North American continent.
>
> The grass of Brobdingnag is as tall as a tree. He is then found by a farmer who is about 72 ft (22 m) tall, judging from Gulliver estimating the man's step being 10 yards (9 m). The giant farmer brings Gulliver home, and his daughter Glumdalclitch cares for Gulliver. The farmer treats him as a curiosity and exhibits him for money. After a while the constant display makes Gulliver sick, and the farmer sells him to the queen of the realm. Glumdalclitch (who accompanied her father while exhibiting Gulliver) is taken into the queen's service to take care of the tiny man. Since Gulliver is too small to use their huge chairs, beds, knives and forks, the queen commissions a small house to be built for him so that he can be carried around in it; this is referred to as his "travelling box".

There are two more travels, but they are often omitted in the more bowdlerized junior versions. And while the Lilliput and Brobdingnag segments aren't entirely kid-friendly (in the first, Gulliver ends a fire with a full bladder, and in the second, there's descriptions of his encounters with giant breasts), they're often sanitized to the point where there was [a Mickey Mouse version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver_Mickey).

Comment: Truly?  I had no idea there were versions that left out Laputa and the Houyhnhnms.

Comment: Assuming we *aren't* being trolled, the answer must be something a *little* more obscure than *Gulliver's Travels*. *Gulliver* can't be the only story with little people, giants, and boats. If it's a real question, it needs more detail.

Comment: I read the junior version without Laputa etc. when I was a junior

Comment: @DavidW They’re often omitted in versions intended to be read by children, as they both get into philosophical territory that most modern Western cultures consider a bit too harsh for children.

Comment: Honestly, even more common is just the Lilliput version, almost always including the "bound to the ground while asleep, and easily sitting up" bit since it's rather iconic. Sometimes, it's an adaptation, sometimes a reference/tribute to the original work but starring another character like Mickey.

Comment: @user14111 There's literally every third or fourth Norse myth. String a few together into one book and it sounds like the same thing.

Comment: @DavidW As a kid in elementary school I read 2 (different) Dutch translations and a comic book version and none of them had Laputa or the Houyhnhnm. In high school English class  we had to read a version that had the Houyhnhnm, but not Laputa. It wasn't until I was in my early 30's that i got an unabridged version and discovered Laputa.

Comment: Possibly also of note, and also left out from the "lite" versions: The Lilliputians aren't only small in stature. Their thoughts and their politics and their prejudices all are centered on trivial matters. Gulliver perceives that right away, and he holds them somewhat in contempt. But then in Brobdingnag, the tables are turned on him, and he cannot understand why the Brobdingnagians think that _his_ thoughts, etc. are trivial. The first three sections are thinly veiled criticism of segments of Swift's own society, and the final "Houyhnhnms" section excoriates the whole human race.

Comment: @DavidW I think the first version I read was in a school literature book and it only included Lilliput.

Comment: The bowdlerized versions also typically leave out the Lilliputian's long-lasting horrifically bloody war about which end of the soft-boiled egg should be broken first at breakfast time. The original was ruthless political satire that just happened to be in a fantasy setting. Not meant for children at all.